# Firefox: URL in URL dropdown, but not in history: can not be deleted

Tags: firefox, history, dropdownlist

There's a URL in the dropdown menu that I can not find in the history. Usually I can delete a URL from history and it also disappears from the dropdown menu. How can I get rid of this URL?

[image: Sites dropdown showing a URL]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, deleting a site from the history should usually remove it from the proposed sites in the URL dropdown.

In this case this is probably a pinned site for the Firefox Home page in a freshly opened tab causing this.

Open a new tab.

If the tab is empty, no shortcuts are displayed temporarily change these settings:

1. Go to Preferences > Home (Open `about:preferences#home`)
2. For "New tabs" change "Blank page" to "Firefox Home"
3. Enable "Shortcuts"

[image: Required preferences]

Open a new tab again.

Now you should see the shortcuts.

Unpin the entry via the `...` menu.

[image: How to unpin]

Finally revert the previous changes.